# Moto G Play (2021) is not detected on Windows PC

Tags: usb, file-transfer, motorola-moto-g

I'm trying to connect my Moto G Play (2021) to my PC with Windows XP SP3 and my computer doesn't know it's even there, where do I get Windows drivers for me to transfer what I want from phone to PC?

Comment: Like Heitor in the answer below said, did you try MTP mode? Is your device still not detected? Are you sure the USB port of your PC and the USB cable you are using are alright?

Comment: For USB drivers: [Where can I download the USB drivers for my device?](https://support.motorola.com/us/en/drivers)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the device is connected in charge mode. Verify if the USB connection type is displayed in notifications, then open it and choose File transfer (MTP).